# Generating a SHA256 hash in python and javascript leads to different results

Tags: encoding, hash, cryptography, cryptojs, cross-language

I have a problem with encrypting plaintext.

What i am doing in Python:

```py
def encrypt(plaintext):
    import hashlib, base64

    hashed = hashlib.sha256(plaintext).digest()
    return base64.b64encode(hashed)

def main():
    input_value = "a"
    output = encrypt(plaintext=input_value)
    print output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result in Python:

```
ypeBEsobvcr6wjGzmiPcTaeG7/gUfE5yuYB3ha/uSLs=
```

What I am doing in JS:

```js
var result = '';
var plaintext = 'a';

if(plaintext != null && plaintext != undefined) {
    var hashed = CryptoJS.SHA256(plaintext);
    result = hashed.toString(CryptoJS.Base64);
}

alert(result);
```

Result in JS:

```
ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Or is there a way to get the same encryption result in both languages?

By the way: It would be easier for me to change the python code, because I already have CryptoJS-encrypted values in my database.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That was simply a copy & paste error from my code. It should be "output = encrypt(plaintext=input_value)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CryptoJS mostly doesn't throw errors. You're passing `undefined` into `hashed.toString(CryptoJS.Base64);`. Use `CryptoJS.enc.Base64`, because `CryptoJS.enc.Hex` is used by default.

But since you prefer to change python, I would suggest to do the hashing [this way](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest):

```py
def encrypt(plaintext):
    import hashlib, base64
    return hashlib.sha256(plaintext).hexdigest()
```

You should still change the JavaScript code to hex encoding for when CryptoJS changes the default behavior.

Comment: Alternately, since he said he would prefer to change the Python code, he can use [`.hexdigest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) and not do base64 encoding.

Comment: Thanks, noticed the sentence only after posting the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! That helped me a lot! Now I have to figure out if I will patch my database or change the python code.What would you recommend?

Comment: @gimlithedwarf This is hard to answer. There are too many possibilities. If you are pressed for space, you can convert it to Base64 and save ~33% space in this column. If you ever send this as a URL parameter, you should either keep it in hex or convert it to the URL-safe version of Base64 (table 2 in RFC 4648).